# Getting sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sqlite, tkinter

```py
c.execute("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE oid = " + record_id)
c.execute("DELETE from addresses WHERE oid = " + delete_box.get)
```

These are the two lines where the error is shown
I did read an answer here on stackoverflow but the error wasnt rectified.

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nampoothiri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Nampoothiri\OneDrive\Desktop\College\Python\EXPERIMENT 6\TKINTER.py", line 153, in delete
    c.execute("DELETE from addresses WHERE oid = " + delete_box.get())
sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input
```

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nampoothiri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Nampoothiri\OneDrive\Desktop\College\Python\EXPERIMENT 6\TKINTER.py", line 89, in edit
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE oid = " + record_id);
sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input
```

These are the errors that keep showing.

Comment: Fist of all please show the full error message. Second of all try changing `delete_box.get` to `delete_box.get()`

Comment: @TheLizzard thanks the error is now resolved

Answer (score 1):

In your problem, the error is encountering about incomplete input error. There is various way to avoid this error. If you are storing that thing into variables then there is another way. But if you are fetching data by the get function then you can try .....

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM addresses WHERE oid = ?", (delete_box.get(),))
```